# Python Server with CherryPy and Mako Template - Nothing is displayed in the browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, cherrypy, mako

I have this project.

Directory:

```
myProject
└── app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── application.py 
    └── view.py
├── templates
    └── template1.mako
├── server.conf
└── server.py
```

server.py:

```
# coding: utf-8

import os.path
import cherrypy
import sys

from app import application

def main():

    try:
        currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    except:
        currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.executable))
    cherrypy.Application.currentDir = currentDir

    configFileName = 'server.conf'
    if os.path.exists(configFileName) == False:
        configFileName = None

    cherrypy.engine.autoreload.unsubscribe()
    cherrypy.engine.timeout_monitor.unsubscribe()

    cherrypy.quickstart(application.Application(), config=configFileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

server.conf:

```
[global]
tools.log_headers.on: True
tools.sessions.on:    False
tools.encode.on:      True
tools.encode.encoding:"utf-8"

server.socket_port:   8080
server.socket_timeout:60

server.thread_pool:  10
server.environment:  "production"
log.screen:          True

[/]
tools.staticdir.root: cherrypy.Application.currentDir
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = '.'
```

template1.mako:

```
## coding: utf-8
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Forum
        </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Forum
        </h1>
        <form>
            Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit!!!">
        </form>
        <div>
            Discussions
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
## EOF
```

application.py:

```
import cherrypy
from app.view import View

class Application(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.myView = View(cherrypy.Application.currentDir)

    def index(self):
        self.myView.create("template1.mako")
    index.exposed = True
```

view.py:

```
import os.path
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup

class View(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.templatesPath = os.path.join(path, 'templates')
        self.myLookup = TemplateLookup(directories=[self.templatesPath])

    def create(self, templateName):
        myTemplate = self.myLookup.get_template(templateName)
        return myTemplate.render()
```

When I start the server in cmd.exe with this command within the myProject folder:

```
python server.py
```

The server works:

```
ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
ENGINE Bus Starting
ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080
ENGINE Bus Started
```

But when I go to localhost:8080 in the Browser, nothing is displayed. Just white. Although there are no errors.
I am pretty sure that `server.py, server.conf and forum.mako` are correct.
It has something to do with the `application.py and view.py` files and the import.
I import view.py in application.py with:

```
from app.view import View
```

And then I use the View class in application.py. I get no errors.
I don't understand what's wrong with my Project. I am sitting here since 5 hours and try do understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `application.py` you forgot to return the rendered template.

```
import cherrypy
from app.view import View

class Application(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.myView = View(cherrypy.Application.currentDir)

    def index(self):
        return self.myView.create("template1.mako")
    index.exposed = True
```

The `return` on the index method.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. 5 hours of troubleshooting because of a little "return" ...